# Clear the People Picker control on button click

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, people-picker

I am using the [People Picker](https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/PeoplePicker/) control in my SPFx web part.

I want to clear the value of this control on the button click.

as mentioned in the comments [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/issues/19), I tried to set the value of `defaultSelectedUsers` property to an empty array but still, I am not able to clear the people picker.

How can I achieve the above behavior?

Comment: It should work something like this:

`private clearPeoplePicker() {
    this.setState({
      selectedtUsers:[]
    })
  }`

any error that you are facing ? This assumes that you store the selected users in the `selectedtUsers` in the state and pass it to the component

Comment: @GautamSheth I already tried the same but it is not working. the state value is set to empty array but the control still holds the selected value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a refer to reference the people picker control so you could clear the value.

```
<PeoplePicker
              context={this.props.context}
              titleText="People Picker"
              personSelectionLimit={3}
              groupName={''}
              showtooltip={false}
              isRequired={false}
              disabled={false}
              selectedItems={this._getPeoplePickerItems}
              defaultSelectedUsers={this.state.PeoplePickerDefaultItems}
              showHiddenInUI={false}
              principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
              resolveDelay={1000}
              ref={c => (this.ppl = c)} 
            />
            <br/>
            <button onClick={() => {this.ppl.state.selectedPersons=[];this.ppl.onChange([]); console.log(this.ppl);/*this.setState({PeoplePickerDefaultItems: []})*/}}>Clear User</button>
```

Declare a variable in class(component)

```
protected ppl;
```